# $F_k(a_1,b_1,c_1;a_2,b_2,c_2)=\int_0^k\frac{a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1}{a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, closed-form

I would like to know a general closed form for
$$J=F_k(a_1,b_1,c_1;a_2,b_2,c_2)=\int_0^k\frac{a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1}{a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2}\mathrm{d}x$$
Where $k>0$, $4a_1c_1-b_1^2<0$, and $4a_2c_2-b_2^2<0$. I encounter forms of the integral all the time and I thought it would be beneficial to finally put that to rest. I already know that 
$$I_k(a,b,c)=\int_0^k\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{ax^2+bx+c}=\frac1g\bigg[\arctan\bigg(\frac{2ak+b}g\bigg)-\arctan\bigg(\frac bg\bigg)\bigg]$$
where $g=\sqrt{4ac-b^2}$

Hence we have that $$J=a_1\int_0^k\frac{x^2}{a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2}\mathrm{d}x+b_1\int_0^k\frac{x}{a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2}\mathrm{d}x+c_1I_k(a_2,b_2,c_2)$$
So really one must focus on the integrals 
$$H=\int_0^k\frac{x^2}{a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$W=\int_0^k\frac{x}{a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2}\mathrm{d}x$$
They don't seem especially hard, but I just keep getting lost in the algebra with the constants. Could I have a bit of help? Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting notation. Why do you choose to have $k$ as a subscript to $F$? (usually, these kind of subscripts denote "different functions" and not the main argument of the function)

Comment: @Fabian Purely an aesthetic choice.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B(a1+x%5E2+%2B+b1+x+%2B+c1)%2F(a2+x%5E2+%2B+b2+x+%2B+c2),+x%5D) is your friend... Just take the result of the antiderivative and insert the boundaries by hand.

Comment: Do you mean $b_i^2 - 4 a_i c_i < 0$?

Comment: @Travis yes I did

Comment: Sorry, I'm guessing $a_1, a_2 \neq 0 $ ?

Comment: @DavidG I think so, because $a_i,b_i,c_i\in\Bbb R$ and if $a_i=0$ then $b_i^2-4a_ic_i=b_i^2<0$ which is a contradiction

Comment: Ah yes, didn't see that was wrapped up in your other condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's natural to compute the integrals $$\int_0^k \frac{x^n \,dx}{a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2},$$
it's somewhat more efficient to decompose the integral in a different way. (Herein we suppose $a_2 \neq 0$; the case $a_2 = 0$ is easier.)

Notice that we can write the numerator of the integrand as
$$\frac{a_1}{a_2}(a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2) + B x + C$$
for some constants $B, C$ (that we can write explicitly in terms of the $a_i, b_i, c_i$), so we can write the integral as
$$\int_0^k \frac{a_1 x^2 + b_1 x + c_1}{a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2} dx
= k \cdot \frac{a_1}{a_2} + \color{#df0000}{\int_0^k \frac{B x + C}{a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2} dx} .$$
Now, with a view toward applying the substitution $$u = a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2, \qquad du = 2 a_2 x + b_2 ,$$
we can write the numerator of the second integrand as $$B x + C = \frac{B}{2 a_2} (2 a_2 x + b_2) + D$$
for some constant $D$ (that again we can write explicitly). So, the integral on the right-hand side is
$$\color{#df0000}{\int_0^k \frac{B x + C}{a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2} dx} = \frac{B}{2 a_2} \int_0^k \frac{2 a_2 x + b_2}{a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c} dx + D \int_0^k \frac{dx}{a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2} .$$ Rewriting the first term on the r.h.s. with the above substitution gives
$$\frac{B}{2 a_2} \int_{c_2}^{a_2 k^2 + b_2 k + c_2} \frac{du}{u},$$ and the second integral on the r.h.s. is the quantity you denoted $I_k(a, b, c)$, for which you've already found an expression.

Comment: Thanks. This is a really neat (and efficient!) approach.

Comment: You're welcome. If you just treat the integrals $\int \frac{x^k \,dx}{a x^2 + b x + c}$ directly you'll find that you have to do the computations that come up in the method in my answer anyway, but some you'll have to do more than once. The method in the answer just decomposes the numerator in a way such that you only have to deal with each type of manipulation exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

The process should work the same way with the integral you call $I$. Pull out $a$ in the denominator, complete the square, substitute $u = x + b/2a$, pull out $(4ac-b^{2})/4a^{2}$ from denominator and substitute $y = 2au/\sqrt{4ac-b^{2}}$), and then you should arrive at three elementary integrals

$$ \int\frac{x^{2}\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2}+1} \quad\quad \int\frac{x\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2}+1} \quad\quad \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2}+1}.$$

As a result of the first substitution, you should have all three of the integrals above to evaluate for integral $H$, and two of them for integral $W$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly
simple-minded first step.

$\begin{array}\\
H
&=\int_0^k\dfrac{x^2}{a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2}dx\\
&=\dfrac1{a_2}\int_0^k\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+b^*_2x+c_2^*}dx\\
&=\dfrac1{a_2}\int_0^k\dfrac{x^2+b^*_2x+c_2^*-(b^*_2x+c_2^*)}{x^2+b^*_2x+c_2^*}dx\\
&=\dfrac1{a_2}\int_0^k\left(1-\dfrac{b^*_2x+c_2^*}{x^2+b^*_2x+c_2^*}\right)dx\\
&=\dfrac1{a_2}\left(k-\int_0^k\left(\dfrac{b^*_2x}{x^2+b^*_2x+c_2^*}\right)dx-\int_0^k\left(\dfrac{c_2^*}{x^2+b^*_2x+c_2^*}\right)dx\right)\\
\end{array}
$

So $H$ reduces to
the other two,
one of which you know.